# How to convert a datatype as object?

Tags: python, numpy

The DTypes <class 'numpy.dtype[float64]'> and <class 'numpy.dtype[datetime64]'> do not have a common DType. For example they cannot be stored in a single array unless the dtype is `object`.

Comment: getting this error whenever i am trying to fit the model

Comment: Don't use comments to add info to your question. [Edit] the question instead. Anyway, what model are you talking about? Please provide more context. See [ask] for tips, like providing a [mre].